# Angular 2: Modal open event

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

in my Angular 2 application, I am using [modal component](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals):

```
<div bsModal #addRecordModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog ">
  <div class="modal-header">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style="min-height: 270px;">
      <app-my-test [modal]="addRecordModal"></app-edit-record>
  </div>
  ...
```

In the modal-body, there is the **MyTestComponent**, which contains ModalDirective:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() modal: ModalDirective;
    ...
```

I wonder if it is possible somehow to **detect modal open** event inside the MyTestComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare $ as any and then you will have access to all these events mentioned here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp
In shown.bs.modal function, you can set this.modalShown as true which will be passed to your child component using  @Input. You can listen for changes to this input in child component using ngonchanges.Hope this helps you.